# What's the difference between networking on your own vs at an MBA program?

Tags: education, networking

An alleged advantage of an MBA over other (often cheaper) postgraduate management education options is that it offers an opportunity to network.

In case I am already good at networking, go to many industry events and not only... and am generally very socially active in many spheres, what's the difference of that type of networking from the MBA type of networking? What's the real "networking opportunity" that an MBA provides that one cannot get on their own?

Comment: An MBA does not magically allow you to network.  You still have to network.  So networking shouldn't even be on the list for reasons to get an MBA

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about navigating the workplace

Comment: Have you considered who else may have taken that program, who teaches that program, what companies may recruit from that program? Each of those is a possible network to tap.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are missing seeing is that the MBA network extends well beyond the people you go to school with into the senior corporate people who also hold the same degree from the same institution. That is the network advantage as most senior level people have an MBA (it being the basic qualification for entry into the senior ranks many places) and not a certificate.  This is also why it makes a huge difference which MBA program you go to. The course material is similar (altough some programs will be better inthis aspect as well), the reputation and the network is not. So if you get an MBA from Harvard, you have a network connection to all the senior managers who also got that degree from Harvard. Since the more senior the people in your network,  the better job opportunities they might have for you, the better the chances of getting one of those senior jobs yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two components to the benefits of an MBA program in general:

1. Which program has stronger members? I can't answer that and not all programs are alike. You pick the one which is best for you, but typically an MBA program should attract better candidates. Like you said, they cost more and there is a reason for that. All things being equal, if you're going to be good at networking, why not network in the best pool.
2. MBA programs allow you to engage in work-like activities. I'm not going to recommend someone just because I met him/her at some convention as oppose to the person I worked with directly on a project. This gives me a much better idea of how smart, knowledgeable, hard working, easy to get along with, etc. the people are.

These two complement one another. Of course you can meet MBA-types at professional social events, but not do any real work. In the other programs, you can engage in real-work activities and debates, but the quality of individuals may not be there.

Who has the people you would partner with in a start up. want on your team? Again, not all programs are the same, so you have to do a little research to see which ones are a best fit for you and can help you with your career the most.

Answer (score 0):

It is good to have multiple networks.

You should have non-work networks:family network, neighborhood network, family related network (kids school, kids sports team)...

You should have company networks. Past and present.

You should also have technical networks.

If the only thing you get from the MBA program is another network opportunity it might not be enough of a benefit for the cost. If you see a benefit for a non-MBA advanced degree that might be a much better choice. The networking opportunities for the wrong degree are unlikely to be worth the money.